# Deletar dados de 3 tabelas diferentes (Codeigniter)

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, delete

Estou tentando deletar fotos de uma view, porém, preciso apagar além da tabela de fotos os dados de mais duas tabelas que estão vinculadas a essa de fotos.

O código com a função delete está o seguinte:

```
function deleteImage($id)
{
    $this->db->select('idImagem')->from('tbdimagem')->where('idImagem', $id);
    $subQuery =  $this->db->get_compiled_select();

    $tabelas = array('tbdsubcategoria', 'tbdcategoria', 'tbdimagem');
    $this->db->where('idImagem', $subQuery);
    $this->db->delete($tabelas);
}
```

**Porém ele retorna isso ao executar a função na view:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT 1**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT 2**

**Tabela Imagem**

[image: Tabela Imagem]

**Tabela Categoria**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela Subcategoria**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, nas duas tabelas 'filhas' precisei colocar o parâmetro '**on delete cascade**' nas chaves estrangeiras. Após isso, consegui excluir os dados a partir da tabela 'pai'.

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria da seguinte maneira

```
function deleteImage($id){

    $this->db->where('idImagem', $id);
    $delete_tbdsubcategoria = $this->db->delete('tbdsubcategoria');

    $this->db->where('idImagem', $id);
    $delete_tbdcategoria = $this->db->delete('tbdcategoria');   

    $this->db->where('idImagem', $id);
    $delete_tbdimagem = $this->db->delete('tbdimagem');

}
```

Comment: Editei meu post com um print do resultado sobre esse código que você mandou

Comment: Poste também sua estrutura das tabelas, pra gente analisar... porque ali diz que não eixste idImagem na tabela indicada.

Comment: Coloquei no post as tabelas. Só para deixar claro, na tabela Tbdimagem o campo idImagem é chave primária, e nas tabelas Tbdcategoria e Tbdsubcategoria o campo idImagem é chave estrangeira.